# make http post request with reactJs and NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http

I have a registration form in one of my reactJs files, which takes all values of input fields (works as I expect). 
**SignUp.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class SignUpForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            username: '',
            hasAgreed: false,
            formErrors: {email: '', password: ''},
            emailValid: false,
            passwordValid: false,
            formValid: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        let target = e.target;
        let value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        let name = target.name;

        this.setState({[name]: value});
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('The form was submitted with the following data:');

        console.log([this.state.email, cryptr.encrypt(this.state.password), this.state.username, this.state.hasAgreed]);

       //I want to send my above data to node server

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="FormCenter">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="FormFields" method="POST" action="/register">
                    <div className="FormField">
                        <label htmlFor="name">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your username" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="FormField">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <div className="FormField">
                        <label htmlFor="email">E-Mail Address</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="FormField">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="hasAgreed" value={this.state.hasAgreed} onChange={this.handleChange} /> I agree all statements in <a href="google.com">terms of service</a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SignUpForm;
```

Now I want to send the mentioned data to the created node server.
**server.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "src/containers/user")));

//the request in which I expect input data
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    console.log(req.body, "body");
    res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("is listening on port 5000");
});
```

As I expect, in **form** tag writing `method="POST" action="/register"`would do it's job, but even the `console.log` from `/register` request is not responding.

**Note:** The next thing I should implement is to write all the data in txt file. So fetching the data in back end is a must.

Comment: Use apisauce or axios, otherwise you have to do an old fashioned XMLHttpRequest call

Comment: writing this inside **handleSubmit** didn't help
`axios.post('/register')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
`

Comment: You’re not sending anything with your post. The second argument is supposed to be your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is pass the data as an object to axios like so, which you indicated you have installed in your project.

```
const formData = {
    email: this.state.email,
    password: cryptr.encrypt(this.state.password)
    username: this.state.username,
    hasAgreed: this.state.hasAgreed
}

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/register',
    data: formData,
    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
})
.then(function (response) {
    //handle success
})
.catch(function (response) {
    //handle error
});
```

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 404. This is what I get.

Comment: Is “/register” on the same server as your React app? You may need to put a full http path

Comment: No I use two separate servers, one is for reactJs another one is node server. where should I put the full path?

Comment: Where it says “url”, change “/register” to the full path

Answer (score -1):

The default behavior of a form is to submit when a submit button is clicked, or if a user hits enter. In your case however, you have a submit handler like so;

```
handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('The form was submitted with the following data:');

        console.log([this.state.email, cryptr.encrypt(this.state.password), this.state.username, this.state.hasAgreed]);

       //I want to send my above data to node server

    }
```

In this handler your are writing `e.preventDefault();` which as the name implies, prevents the form's default behavior from happening. As a result no request is actually being made to the server.

Now the surest way I know to make this work, would be to use some kind of ajax library. You can use fetch, or something like axios.

The other way which MAY work is to remove the `e.preventDefault();`. Now this way is a bit more tricky. Usually react apps are not served from the same server as the api, in which case your request's url would need to look something more like this.
`http://localhost:5000/register`. Alternatively, you can tell webpack dev server to proxy your requests. Even then I personally am not sure this would work simply because I have never tried it.

Its important to note, either approach you choose will require the full url in the request if the react app is not served from the same place as the api, or if there is no proxying done by wepback. In other words, you may very well need `http://localhost:5000/register`.

My suggestion would be to use an ajax library like I mentioned.

Hope this helps.